# "Allow Mock location" option is not visible on AVD or actual device

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, cts

How to enable "Allow Mock location" in Android 6 as it is a precondition to run CTS . Where as now in place of "Allow Mock location" , "Select mock location app " option is available .

phone settings >> Developer option  >> ??

Points :
1.Is the option removed or not required for running CTS

Note:
The Google CTS page says ""Allow Mock location"" has to be enabled .